# PHP Associative Array, same code on same level doesn't work

Tags: php, arrays, associative

I have a really strange problem over here. Sorry for the ugly redundant parts, but it is only for prototyping. In both blocks I calculate the seconds of the given worktime. The first block was the first version and worked, but wasn't that robust. So the second block solved the robustness problem. 
The important part is
`$hours[$row["gamemaster"]] = $hours[$row["gamemaster"]] + $worktime;`

In both blocks the integer $worktime is in seconds. But now the problem is, that in the second block the sum of the worktime doesn't work. It's on the same level, and there are no changes at other parts of the code.

The expected value is the sum of the working hours for each gamemaster. In the first block the printed value is the time as expected and in the second block nothing happens. And my big question mark is, that the calculation of the sum is exactly the same and only the calculation of the worktime before is different. And if I add only normal integers in the second block like `$hours[$row["gamemaster"]] = $hours[$row["gamemaster"]] + 1;` nothing happens, but for the first block, also something strange like `$hours[$row["gamemaster"]] = $hours[$row["gamemaster"]] + "p";` worked.

first block:

```
if($row["no_game"]==0) {
    $worktime = strtotime($row["additional"]);
    $worktime = $worktime + 5400;

    $hours[$row["gamemaster"]] = $hours[$row["gamemaster"]] + $worktime;
  }
  else {
    $worktime = strtotime($row["additional"]);

    $hours[$row["gamemaster"]] = $hours[$row["gamemaster"]] + $worktime;
  }
```

output first block for $hours: 
[key]:[value] 
Felix:8778047400 
Marie:2926018800

second block:

```
  if($row["no_game"]==0) {
    $str_time = $row["additional"];
    $str_time = preg_replace("/^([\d]{1,2})\:([\d]{2})$/", "00:$1:$2", $str_time);
    sscanf($str_time, "%d:%d:%d", $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
    $time_seconds = $hours * 3600 + $minutes * 60 + $seconds;
    $worktime = $time_seconds + 5400;

    $hours[$row["gamemaster"]] = $hours[$row["gamemaster"]] + $worktime;
  }
  else {
    $str_time = $row["additional"];
    $str_time = preg_replace("/^([\d]{1,2})\:([\d]{2})$/", "00:$1:$2", $str_time);
    sscanf($str_time, "%d:%d:%d", $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
    $worktime = $hours * 3600 + $minutes * 60 + $seconds;

    $hours[$row["gamemaster"]] = $hours[$row["gamemaster"]] + $worktime;
  }
```

output second block for $hours:
Nothing, like nothing is written in the array

Update 1:
I reduce the code of the second block to

```
    $str_time = $row["additional"];
    $str_time = preg_replace("/^([\d]{1,2})\:([\d]{2})$/", "00:$1:$2", $str_time);
    sscanf($str_time, "%d:%d:%d", $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
    $time_seconds = $hours * 3600 + $minutes * 60 + $seconds;
    $worktime = $time_seconds + 5400;Update 1:
```

I reduce the code of the second block to

```
    $str_time = $row["additional"];
    $str_time = preg_replace("/^([\d]{1,2})\:([\d]{2})$/", "00:$1:$2", $str_time);
    sscanf($str_time, "%d:%d:%d", $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
    $time_seconds = $hours * 3600 + $minutes * 60 + $seconds;
    $worktime = $time_seconds + 5400;
    $hours[$row["gamemaster"]] = $hours[$row["gamemaster"]] + $worktime;
```

There are 8 iterations over the dataset and the output for $worktime afer each iteration is: 
1: 7200 
2: 5400 
3: 5400 
4: 7200 
5: 7200 
6: 7200 
7: 5400 
8: 5400 

But there is still no entry in $hours.

Comment: Before summing up `$hours[$row["gamemaster"]]` and `$worktime`, make a debug print to see their exact values, and try to understand why the sum "doesn't work" as you expect. If it keeps "not working", please better specify what "doesn't work" means...

Comment: okay sry. In this case "not working" means: I print at the end the key-value-pair, to see the working hours for each gamemaster. In the first block it prints it like espected: "name" : "hours". But in the second block it does nothing. Not even add a key to the array, with no value. Even if I write `$hours[$row["gamemaster"]] = $hours[$row["gamemaster"]] + 1;`

Comment: What is the expected value? What is the printed value? What are the addenda values?

Comment: The expected value is the sum of the working hours for each gamemaster. In the first block the printed value is the time as expected and in the second block nothing happens. And my big question mark is, that the calculation of the sum is exactly the same and only the calculation of the worktime before is different. And if I add only normal integers in the second block like `$hours[$row["gamemaster"]] = $hours[$row["gamemaster"]] + 1;` nothing happens, but for the first block, also something strange like `$hours[$row["gamemaster"]] = $hours[$row["gamemaster"]] + "p";` worked.

Comment: Please update your question with the answer to my previous comment, writing the **values** you get from both the blocks...

Comment: O.k. So, we need to debug last block. First, remove `if($row["no_game"]==0) {` test, and keep only one case. Then, print the value of any variable after assignment. For example: `$str_time = $row["additional"]; var_dump($str_time)`, and so on...

Comment: Oh I forget to mention something important. I print also the worktime after each iteration and it's everytime a integervalue between 5000 and 10000. I also reduce the second block to the if-case and delete `if($row["no_game"]==0) {`. But still no output.

Comment: You should add the code with the debug prints **and their output** to your question, otherwise it's difficult to help you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is you're overwriting the `$hours` variable within your `sscanf` call.

```
$rows = [
    ['gamemaster' => 1, 'additional' => '00:30:00', 'no_game' => 0],
    ['gamemaster' => 2, 'additional' => '00:10:30', 'no_game' => 0],
    ['gamemaster' => 3, 'additional' => '00:20:00', 'no_game' => 0],
    ['gamemaster' => 1, 'additional' => '00:40:40', 'no_game' => 1],
    ['gamemaster' => 2, 'additional' => '00:15:00', 'no_game' => 1],
    ['gamemaster' => 3, 'additional' => '00:00:30', 'no_game' => 1],
    ['gamemaster' => 1, 'additional' => '00:00:10', 'no_game' => 0],
    ['gamemaster' => 2, 'additional' => '00:20:30', 'no_game' => 0],
    ['gamemaster' => 3, 'additional' => '00:00:00', 'no_game' => 0],
    ['gamemaster' => 1, 'additional' => '00:05:00', 'no_game' => 1],
    ['gamemaster' => 2, 'additional' => '00:09:40', 'no_game' => 1],
    ['gamemaster' => 3, 'additional' => '00:18:30', 'no_game' => 1],
    ['gamemaster' => 1, 'additional' => '00:34:30', 'no_game' => 0],
    ['gamemaster' => 2, 'additional' => '00:59:59', 'no_game' => 0],
    ['gamemaster' => 3, 'additional' => '00:40:00', 'no_game' => 0]
];

$result = array();

foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $str_time = preg_replace('/^([\d]{1,2})\:([\d]{2})$/', "00:$1:$2", $row['additional']);
    sscanf($str_time, '%d:%d:%d', $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
    $worktime = $hours * 3600 + $minutes * 60 + $seconds;
    if (!$row['no_game']) {
        $worktime += 5400;
    }
    if (!isset($hours[$row['gamemaster']])) {
        $result[$row['gamemaster']] = 0;
    }
    $result[$row['gamemaster']] += $worktime;
}

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Oh thank you, what an awkward mistake. Now everything is working as expected. Thank you so much.

Comment: Believe me @datafridge - we've ALL been there, done it and got the t-shirt and we never learn from it ;) Sometimes it takes a fresh pair of eyes just to see these things.